# Microsoft Graph API result is not treated as a JSON object in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, json.net, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions

I'm fetching group information from the Microsoft Graph API and it returns results as:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups(id,displayName,description)",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "description": "Admin",
      "displayName": "Admin"
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "description": "End user",
      "displayName": "EndUser"
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "description": "Administrator",
      "displayName": "Administrator"
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "description": "XXX",
      "displayName": "XXX"
    }
  ]
}
```

I return this string from the server as:

```
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, groups);
```

In AngularJS 1.6 at the client side it is treated as a string, not as a JSON object.  Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are apparently returning a JSON string from within a Web API method.  By default, Web API automatically serializes anything you give it.  So if you give it a JSON string, that string will get re-serialized, meaning the client would have to deserialize it twice to get at the object.  If you want to pass pre-formatted JSON through untouched, you need to explicitly create the response content as a string so that it will not get double serialized by Web API.

Try it like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(groups, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return response;
```